# How to know which jar file of android sdk contains the class I need

Tags: android, eclipse, android-uiautomator

I want to recreate android uiautomator.jar (not the whole android framework) in eclipse from its source code, and need to:

```
import android.accessibilityservice.UiTestAutomationBridge; 
import android.os.SystemService;
```

but saw the following errors:

```
package android.accessibilityservice does not exist
package android.os does not exist
```

I am using android sdk-17. From the source code coming with the sdk, I can see that the packages do exist, they are under sources/android-17/android, and I can see the java source files are there.

My build path contains only android.jar, obviously it does not includes these packages. Is there a way to know which jar I should include? I understand the whole android framework needs to be compiled in Linux environment. Is it possible to compile uiautomator using Eclipse. It is only a jar file used for UI tetsing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem, what you want is to import a external library in .jar format. (Adding the library in to your project's java build path) In that case you do not need to compile whole framework.
You can import any external library that you want. 
In eclipse:

```
Right click your project >> Select Properties >> Java build path >> Libraries >> Add External JARs
```

and select the library (uiautomator.jar) you need to import from your local disk.

Comment: my real problem is: which jar file contains the java packages (such as android.accessibilityservice, and android.os) I need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways to look inside jar files:

- in Eclipse, you can open jar files, once they're added to a project, and look inside
- in the commandline, you can use `jar -tf`.  For example, if you're on linux, you could try:

  - jar -tf somejarfile.jar | grep accessibilityservice
- on Windows you could try:

  - jar -tf somejarfile.jar | find /i "accessibilityservice"
- ... then just try these on different jar files, until you find the one that contains what you're looking for.